# Why safari browser show large font size compare to other browsers like chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I checked on chrome its font-size look good as I have added on my CSS but when I checked on safari browser font size of **privacy policy** and **terms of use** is larger than chrome browser.

Here is my Html

```
     <div class="term-condition-section">
        <a class="term-condition-btn" target="_blank" href="#">Privacy Policy/</a>
        <a class="term-condition-btn" target="_blank" href="#">Terms of Use</a>
     </div>
```

Here is my Css

```
.term-condition-section {
   display: flex;
   padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}

.term-condition-section .term-condition-btn {
   display: block;
   width: fit-content;
   clear: both;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-size: 10px;
   color: blue;
   text-align: inherit;
   white-space: nowrap;
   background-color: transparent;
   border: 0;
}
```

Please help

Comment: Can I know your font family which you used to these elements please?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your `font-family`, I can't actually tell whether what is the reason for this. Here are some possibilities to this problem.

1. Some font formats aren't supported by Safari.
2. Sometimes there may be no `font-weight: 400;` in your selected `font-family` provided and the output result may vary according to this.

So you can try disabling it by adding `font-synthesis: none` in the text, providing the bold version of your font or changing your font to a [Web Safe Font](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp).

To learn more about `font-synthesis`, please visit [MDN font-synthesis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-synthesis) page

EDIT:

Avenir Next has OTF, TTF type file format so Safari browser version 3.1 to 11.1 doesn't supports it. But however Safari browser version 12 supports it.

For more information, please visit these pages.

[Browser support details for fonts](https://www.lambdatest.com/trueType-and-openType-font-support)

[Avenir Next font details](https://freefontsfamily.com/avenir-next-font-download-free)

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: here is font family: 'AvenirNxt'

Comment: `font-synthesis: none;` <-- this one worked for me for a similar issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your Problem:

```css
  body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  }
```